# run simultaneous spark streaming applications

Tags: hadoop, testing, apache-spark

I'm working with a windows machine whereby a Spark worker and master are installed as a service.

Currently, it's only been used for one streaming application and so far, it's working fine.  I'm now looking at running another streaming application on the same machine and wondering if there is a way to safely achieve this.